# How can I 'bound' a modelformset to an object, fill it and editing in the same page?

Tags: django, django-forms

I m new in Django and development. 
I have a items list, and when I clik on the result button of a test, I would like to have a modelformset for this specific test where i can fill it and editing in the same page.
The code I wrote is 'working' but the problem it's when I fill the form and submit it, it' s editing the same for all the test.

I hope you will understand my explanation( not english speaker)
Here my code:

model.py:

```
class ResultatTest(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
test = models.ForeignKey('Test',  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
services = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=SERV_CHOICES)
notes = models.IntegerField(null=True)
comments = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.services
```

view.py:

```
def resultatTest(request, id):

id = get_object_or_404(Test, pk=id)
ResultatTestFormset = modelformset_factory(ResultatTest,  fields=('test', 'services', 'notes', 'comments'),extra=1)
if request.method == "POST":

    formset = ResultatTestFormset(request.POST)#queryset=form.object.filter(test=test_id)
    if formset.is_valid():
        instances = formset.save(commit= False)
        for instance in instances:
            instance.save()
else:
    formset = ResultatTestFormset()

return render(request, "Portail/Details/resultat.html", {'id': id,'formset': formset})
```

items/test.html:

```
onclick ="window.location ='/resultat/{{test.id}}','_self';
```

url.py:

```
path('resultat/<int:id>/',resultatTest,name='resultat'),
```

resultat.html:

```
  <form action=""  method="post" id="resultatForm ">
 {% csrf_token %}
      <table id='supertable' border=1>
            {{ formset.management_form }}
             {% for form in formset %}

             {% if forloop.first %}
          <tr>
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                 <td style="background: cyan; line-height:1; white-space:nowrap;width:500px;" >{{ field.label_tag }}</td><
             {% endfor %}
         </tr>
            {% endif %}
          <tr>
              {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <td style="background: white; line-height:1; white-space:nowrap;" > {{ field}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
         </tr>
```

{               % endfor %}

I have tried and search a lot of things but I cannot solve my problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you have that onclick. That means you never submit any data. Remove it.

Comment: In fact this onclick is the button ( in the intems list) where I click to get the form template.